# How to delete multiple identical rows with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Some of the records in my table are duplicates. When attempting to delete them, I get this error:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 2 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

The query being called is a simple "DELETE FROM [] WHERE []". I've tried using the Remove method, as well as setting EntityState.Deleted. In both cases it expects the delete call to only hit one row, but it hits two.

How do I make it delete any number of rows fitting the parameters I pass to it?

Comment: If EF trips on these duplicates that means that the primary key (as known to EF) is not unique. That's something you *have to resolve* otherwise EF won't function properly. Which means: you can't use EF to remove the duplicates.

Comment: Not being able to work with tables with no primary key is a flaw in EF as far as I'm concerned. Using some other DB access framework when EF makes 95% of my DB handling easy is also not something I want to do. 

Fortunately, as stated in the answer, EF Plus gets the job done.

Comment: Well, EF (any ORM for that matter) needs a unique identification of entities. That doesn't necessarily have to be a PK, it can be any field (or combination of fields) in a table, as long as it's unique. If you've got a table with records that can't be identified uniquely in any way you should reevaluate some design decisions.

Comment: The database is used and edited by various tools, not all of which I am in control of. Sometimes I just need my program to do exactly what I'm asking. I just wanted the simplest way to make sure it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently EF doesn't include any kind of batch delete, but there's an extension that does: http://entityframework-plus.net/

Can be found on NuGet as Z.EntityFramework.Plus

With that you can chain Where and Delete:

```
context.Table.Where(x => x.field == parameter).Delete();
```

This will work regardless of the number of rows and even if they are duplicates.